# Random undesired big spaces on my pages

Tags: spacing, parskip

I was rereading my document, when I noticed that I am having random spaces. I studied it closely and noticed again that this happens if for example it is followed by a HUGE equation that can not fit on the current page so it automatically starts a new page to put the equation there.
Most of my equations that are very long start with

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    ...\\
    ...\\
    ...
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
```

or instead

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{skip}
    ...\\
    ...\\
    ...
  \end{skip}
\end{equation}
```

My question is what to do with this undesired space? I am thinking the only way is to break the long equations above between the two pages, but I have no clue how this is done? 
If you think there is another way around, please share it with me.

Comment: Put `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble.

Comment: @HarishKumar Thank you, it worked for the ones with `\begin{aligned}..\end{aligned}` BUT not for the `\begin{skip}..\end{skip}`. Is there anyway to solve this?